# Steam API with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, steam, steam-web-api

I'm making a website for rust (video game) where you can gamble items. Anyways, I'm wondering of someone can help me out with my issue: I'm trying to find some sort of API? maybe where the user can login via steam, and I'd have their info to use on the website.
Examples: 
- Their Profile picture
- Their inventory data? (inv items visible)
- Their account name 
etc.

I've seen something in PHP for this that'd probably work, only issue is I'd have to make the site as php and not a .html file (not sure how to change this with angular as I'm new.)
[Steam API wrapper (php) reference](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication)

Anyways, is there a way I can do this with JS or something better *perhaps*? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're looking for in the form of an Angular wrapper exists, but you can find the Web API documentation here:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

You could just build an Angular service to interact with the parts of the API you care about, or you could start building your own wrapper and publish it to GitHub.
You can find a tutorial for building an Angular HTTP Service here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Hmmmm, how would I do that? I'm new to angular but perhaps that might interest me. Otherwise I could probably just use the php thing I mentioned.. but.. I believe I've seen someone do this without it maybe